# Need help on npm start: 'serve' spawn error - code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: google-analytics, npm

I run into error when I tried to host Google Analytics's demo site locally.(https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools)

Please help. Thanks a lot.

I have absolutely no programming / dev background (1st time using Github) and after many hours of struggling I finally made it to this last step, yet still not able to host the site myself.

Tried to update npm and node.js version to the latest but still not working. The first lines of error seeing on command prompt is:

```
Starting 'serve'...
'serve' errored after 6.62ms
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
```

Looking for a solution. The log is below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli 'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.2.0
3 info using node@v7.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~prestart: ga-dev-tools@
6 silly lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~start: ga-dev-tools@
8 verbose lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;c:\GitHub\ga-dev-tools\node_modules.bin;c:\program files\graphicsmagick-1.3.25-q16;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk.install.backup\platform\bundledpython\Scripts;C:\Program Files\GraphicsMagick-1.3.25-Q16;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\GitHub;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git;C:\Program Files\nodejs;;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~start: CWD: c:\GitHub\ga-dev-tools
11 silly lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gulp watch' ]
12 silly lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~start: Returned: code: 1 signal: null
13 info lifecycle ga-dev-tools@~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: ga-dev-tools@ start: gulp watch
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
14 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid ga-dev-tools@
16 verbose cwd c:\GitHub\ga-dev-tools
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v7.8.0
20 error npm v4.2.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error ga-dev-tools@ start: gulp watch
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the ga-dev-tools@ start script 'gulp watch'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ga-dev-tools package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error gulp watch
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error npm bugs ga-dev-tools
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error npm owner ls ga-dev-tools
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```